# Jenkins REST API: Create new Job View

Tags: rest, api, jenkins

I am using the Jenkins REST API to automate our CI process.
The last thing that is missing in the automatization pipeline is the creation of a view if theuser-defined view does not exist.

So far I used:

> jenkins_alias/createView?name=My-Test-View

but it is somehow incomplete and returns the error that:

> the viewtype should be defined

how can I define this viewtype from the RESTAPI? Should I send it in the Url or in the request body?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [this post](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-8927?focusedCommentId=194588&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-194588), this is apparently (a) possible with the REST API and (b) without referencing any weird Hudson stuff.

```
# create the view
curl -vvv -X POST -d @view.xml -H "Content-Type: text/xml" http://localhost:8080/createView?name=MyView

# get the configuration
curl http://localhost:8080/view/MyView/config.xml

# update the view
curl -X POST -d @view.xml -H "Content-Type: text/xml" http://localhost:8080/view/MyView/config.xml
```

*Caveat emptor* - I believe this is undocumented.  According to the [Jenkins REST API documentation](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API), all the REST API can do is:

> 1. retrieve information from Jenkins for programmatic consumption
> 2. trigger a new build
> 3. create/copy jobs

Answer (score 4):

Please try this request as an example:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Jenkins-Crumb:<JENKINS-CRUMB>' --form name=test --form mode=hudson.model.ListView --form json='{"name": "test", "mode": "hudson.model.ListView"}' https://<Jenkins-URL>/createView
```

View types:

- ListView: hudson.model.ListView
- Dashboard (if plugin Dashboard View is installed): hudson.plugins.view.dashboard.Dashboard
- MyView: hudson.model.MyView

Comment: Where is this documented?